# Call external dll function in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have created dll file using C# **Utils.dll** which content function **replace_string** within the class **StringUtils**. The function is successfully call and give result when call within the console application. Now, I have included the dll file in plugins/ansi folder within NSIS.

I have tried to call the function as :

```
Utils.StringUtils::replace_string "E:\\test\\test.txt" 'abcd' 'efgh'
```

I have also tried using CLR

```
 CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD Utils.dll Utils.StringUtils replace_string 3 "E:\\test\\test.txt" 'abcd' 'efgh'
```

And again with System call

```
System::Call 'Utils::StringUtils.replace_string("E:\\test\\test.txt", "abcd", "efgh");'
```

But i got errors while compiling the nsi file. What could be the correct implementation of function in dll file at NSIS?

C# Code :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.IO;


    namespace Utils
    {
        public class StringUtils
        {

            public StringUtils()
            {
            }   
            /// 
            /// Replace the data in the Huge files searching and replacing chunk        
            /// by chunk. It will create new file as filepath + ".tmp" file with        
            /// replaced data        
            /// 
            /// Path of the file
            /// Text to be replaced
            /// Text with which it is replaced        
            public static void replace_string(string filePath, string replaceText, string withText)
            {
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath + ".tmp");

                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string data = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    data = data.Replace(replaceText, withText);

                    data = Regex.Replace(data, replaceText, withText);

                    streamWriter.WriteLine(data);
                }

                streamReader.Close();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            public static void print_text()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Console Application Program:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Utils;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                StringUtils.replace_string("E:\\test\\test.txt", "abcd", "efgh");

                //Class1.print_text();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here i have called the replace_string function from the console application and it successfully executed and give the correct result where as when called within NSIS outputs error.

Comment: System::Call only knows about plain C/Win32 functions...

Comment: How about the second example using CLR doesn't work for me then...

Comment: Just saying it does not work is not helpful, we need to know compiler error messages etc...

Comment: @Anders it is not the error from compiling, its from while executing, Try yourself

Answer (score 0):

NSIS itself can only execute C dll's. But maybe this plugin will help you:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Call_.NET_DLL_methods_plug-in

Comment: i have tried according the url you have sent including the clr.dll in plugins but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise? In which way didn't it work? Did you get an error while compiling (and what error) or while executing?

Comment: Maybe you can give away the secret what error message you got?

Comment: Error in .dll method, Exception occur due to the target of invocation

Comment: If you call your Method as in the example in your original post you have it to change. After the Function name you have to put the number of parameters (3) and then the parameters: `CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD Utils.dll Utils.StringUtils replace_string 3 "E:\\test\\test.txt" 'abcd' 'efgh'`. See the given link for reference.

Comment: And did you get the same error message? Is replace_string a static function? Maybe your function replace_string throws the exception. Have you tried to do nothing in the function to get a clue were the problem occures?

Comment: yes it is static function, i didn't any clue to work within the function in C# coz i am not real programmer of C#.

Comment: Do you have access to the code? can you add the function to your question?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I saw the real Problem:

The CLR PlugIn is built with the .NET Framework 2.0. With this Version it is not possible to start Libraries that were built with newer Versions of the .NET Framework. In your C# Code you have an (unneeded) Line `using System.Linq;`, so your .NET Library is built with
Version 3.5 or higher.

You can ensure to compile your library with the Version 2.0 with this command line call (adapt the file names for your environment):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc /t:library /out:Utils.dll Utils.cs
```

If you are using Visual Studio, you can select the Framework in the options of the project.

If you need to use the Library with a .NET Version newer than 2.0 you can recompile the CLR Plugin. The Source code and the proejct file are included in the Zip File.

---

Here the old ideas you should still take care of:

According to your C# Code some things could go wrong there as there is now error/exception handling done.

Some of the problems that could end in an exception are:

- file not available
- no access to file
- no rights to create the .tmp file

Another Question:

Does calling the second function "print_text()" from NSIS work or does it throw the same exception?

Call it in this way:

```
CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD Utils.dll Utils.StringUtils print_text 0
```

And a third thing: In NSIS you don't have to double the \ in a string, so your call would be

```
CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD Utils.dll Utils.StringUtils replace_string 3 "E:\test\test.txt" 'abcd' 'efgh'
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Well i have also attached the console application program where i have called the function. When the program is executed, it success with correct output. This means file is available, access to file, right to create the .tml file. I think there must be sth missing in function definition but unable to figure it out.

Comment: @NavaStha Updated my answer with a tested solution.